# Is there an -ically suffixed word to describe a duration?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, suffixes, prepositional-phrases, derivational-morphology

We know about chronologically to describe order by time, but is there a word to describe duration?

I want to say something like "school is x-ically taxing", as in, school is heavily taxing on an individual's available time.

Comment: Perhaps *interminably* taxing? {^_^}

Comment: @tchrist you're right, I don't want to. This was just a toy example. If you have some more involved reasoning, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: **Periodically** describes a repeated duration, but not how long it is, or how frequently it repeats.

Comment: That doesn't work because periodically means it has fixed intervals. Thanks though.

Comment: The school routine is'enervating'. I don't understand the need for an 'x-ically' word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could get away with "durationally", but I don't think you'll get anything as specific from another word. Your best bet might be "temporally".

Of course, if the alliteration of "temporally taxing" sounds too whimsical for the context, you have a whole new problem. "temporally inefficient", perhaps?

Comment: Yes; I think you're flogging a dead horse here. +1 for the attempt. The usual sort of work-around would be 'School really makes heavy demands on my [available] time'. _Time_ is marvellously polysemic.

Comment: temporally is my favorite from these responses, thank you. I don't actually want to refer to school, that was just a toy example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say 'school is chronically taxing'. Chronically--Lasting for a long period of time; of long duration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't like chronically due to its connotation, and generally was looking for a more active word. For example, if I wanted to say "talking to you is chronically taxing" it makes less sense, because talking to you isn't something I'm required to do over one long duration, but rather a task that feels long only when I do it.

Answer (score 1):

I pointed out in a comment to the OP that they really did not want to do this, and was asked why. My answer did not fit within the designated comment-length restrictions, so I provide it here.

**TL;DR:**

Even if you do find a suitable value for *XXX*, no one will ever thank you for writing that *“school is* XXX-*istically taxing on/of an individual’s time”* when all you mean is that school heavily taxes an individual’s time: *taxes* is a far stronger verb phrase than *is taxing of* can ever hope to be.

---

The reason you don’t want to do this is because using some big long ugly word which nobody has ever heard of, or perhaps which nobody wants wants to hear, by replacing simple phrases made up of simple words with turgid sesquipedalianisms is an obnoxious and annoying trait which while especially common to texts made by big bureaucracies, is an oft-noted hallmark of bad writing anywhere.

**Language is about the infinite combinations of meaning achieved through *syntactic
arrangement of separate words***, and so the recurring quest to find a single word, howsoever
abstruse and clumsy it may be, to replace a multiword concept with is
quixotically self-defeating if your goal is to be understood.

These many-to-one substitutions of phrases for single words do nothing to make your text clearer  or stronger. Instead you only muddy the waters and make it harder for your reader to figure out what you are trying to say.  It is nearly always better to use a few simple words artfully arranged than to use one fancy one in their stead.

I recommend reading [Helen Sword’s *New York Times* article on “Zombie Nouns” of 23 July 2012](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/07/23/zombie-nouns/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0).  The article opens with the following text, bold emphasis mine:

> Nouns formed from other parts of speech are called nominalizations. **Academics love them; so do lawyers, bureaucrats and business writers.** I call them “zombie nouns” because they cannibalize active verbs, suck the lifeblood from adjectives and substitute abstract entities for human beings[.]

Yes, this article is about nominalizations not adverbializations, but the issues are identical.

Iteratively applying derivational morphology — read, applying a long string of multiple suffixes — to create derived terms will indeed “suck the lifeblood” out of your writing.

This is what happens in pieces written by “academics, lawyers, bureaucrats, and business writers”.   Despite how notorious this practice is, and how universally scorned, they cannot seem to help themselves.   You should aim to do better.

Your desired *-ically* suffix is already two or three suffixes all by itself. That is always going to weaken your writing.  For example, it is better to convey your message *by (using) propaganda* than to communicate it *propagandistically*.

See the difference?

The first uses an ugly and awkward adverbialization, while the other uses a simple adverbial phrase to say the same thing. **The phrase version is better than the single-word version.**

### Summary

Avoid replacing prepositional phrases with single words created by a clattering cascade of suffixes.  English has prepositions for good reason, and you should not be afraid to use them.

Comment: Good read, thanks. _The Elements of Style_ is also a strong advocate of avoiding unnecessarily flowery language, but sometimes there is a reason (fun?) to sound "pompous and abstract". (Sorry, I can't upvote you yet)

Comment: I quite agree. It's fun to be long-winded sometimes. The girl checker at the supermarket noted with curiosity my mundane purchase of a toothbrush.'There's something...something about a toothbrush,' she said holding the object aloft. Without a pause I responded, 'Yes, it's a reaffirmation of my dedication to oral hygeine.' Smiles and giggles all-around.